# CSS pointer events and cursor style

Tags: html, css, ajax

I have a problem with combination of `pointer-events: none` and `cursor: wait`. I need to disable clicking and show waiting cursor while ajax is in process. There is a mechanism that automatically adds or removes `wait` class to `body` tag. Without `pointer-events: none`, the wait cursor appears, and when there are both `cursor: wait` and `pointer-events: none`, the cursor doesn'change but stays a default arrow.

```
.wait {
    cursor:wait;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Is there any way to solve this only with css or i must do the trick with a transparent `div`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disable clicking to what ?

Answer (score 50):

Unless you have click listeners on the body itself, show about this?

```
.wait {
    cursor:wait;
}

.wait > * {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate question but I prefer your answer. thanks

Comment: @Prinzhorn:  Nice solution

Comment: Excellent idea... tnx